# highcharter both nominal and percentage values

Tags: r, highcharts, pie-chart

I've made a pie chart with the highcharter library.

```
library(highcharter)

test_data
  Gender  Freq  colors
1 Female 29813 #ff99cc
2   Male 38474 #2980b9

hchart(test_data, "pie", hcaes(x = Gender, y = Freq, color=colors))
```

As the map is interactive, I want to have the pie chart showing both percentage values and nominal values **on the same plot**.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a formatter with JS() function of highcharter, in the tooltip options. Moreover Highchart uses the `this.point.percentage` to provide the percentages. Make sure not to forget the `%>%` at the end of the first line.

This should do the trick for you:

```
hchart(test_data, "pie", hcaes(x = Gender, label=Gender,y = Freq, color=colors))%>%
```

`hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
                                return  '<b>' + this.point.label + ': </b>( Frequency:' +this.y+', Percentage: '+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage)+'%)'
  }"),useHTML = FALSE)`

by adding the line (again the magrittr '%>%' is needed before or after the line):
 `hc_plotOptions(pie =list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,format="{point.label}:{point.y}")))`

you can add on the labels the values or by exchanging the `{point.y}` with the:

`{point.percentage:.2f}%`, you can add the percentage along with the label (Male,Felame)

Comment: Is there a way to show either nominal value or percent in the labels, while the other one in the tooltip?

Comment: @Prometheus: Yes: by 
`hc_plotOptions(pie =list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,format="{point.label}:{point.y}")))`

you can interchange between point.y with `point.percentage:.2f` to get the %

Answer (score 3):

```
hchart(test_data, "pie", hcaes(x = Gender, y = Freq, color=colors)) %>% 
      hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>Value:</b> {point.y} <br>
                 <b>Percentage</b> {point.percentage:,.2f}%")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include some explanation of your code in order to form a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the nominal value by using `point.y`:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>Value:</b> {point.y:.0f}<br><b>Percentage: {point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
},
```