# Can Highcharter treemap show the percentage?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

How can I add percentage information to the highcarter treemap tooltip?

I tried adding {point.percentage:.0f} to the hc_tooltip, but it's not working.

```
require(treemap)
require(highcharter)
data("GNI2014")

tm <-  treemap(
  GNI2014,
  index = c("continent", "iso3"),
  vSize = "population",
  vColor = "GNI",
      type = "value"
    )

hctreemap(tm = tm) %>% 
hc_tooltip(
pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b><br> {point.value:.0f} <br>{point.percentage:.0f}")
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more accurate explanation. This article should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Do you want this value to be a percentage of the sum of the whole data set?

Comment: Yes exactly, like what the square area shows. I know I can precalculate it and add it as new variable, but my question is whether is it possible to do it through highcharter, because I know it's possible for other types of charts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680182/highcharter-both-nominal-and-percentage-values

Comment: Here's example how to do it in JS using `tooltip.pointFormatter` function: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/chdn4r0d/ I suppose it can be done in R like this: `hc_tooltip(pointFormatter = JS("function(){/* function body goes here*/}")`.

Comment: Yeah that's it! Thanks! You can post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's example of how to do it in **JS** using `tooltip.pointFormatter` function: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/chdn4r0d/

It can be done in **Highcharter** like this:

```
hc_tooltip(pointFormatter = JS("function(){/* function body goes here*/}")
```