# highcharter convert value to percent in tooltip

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, treemap

I've made a treemap in high charter and I want to print the value multiplied by 100 and add a percentage symbol on the end. I currently have this code that produces the image below

```
hchart(dout, type = "treemap")%>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>
                             value: {point.value:.3f}%<br>")
```

[image: treemap tooltip]

I'm thinking I need a JS function to multiply {point.value:.3f} by 100

I've been trying to hack together something [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680182/highcharter-both-nominal-and-percentage-values) but I just don't understand how higcharter or JS work enough to get it. I'm not even sure a JS function is the right way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I don't understand how to integrate the examples provided for me using JS I decided to attack this problem differently and I just added a line earlier in my code to convert the value in the df dout that I am printing out as point.value in the tooltip, by 100 before it gets to the hchart() function.  No change is necessary to the example code I posted initially

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it would be best to use the Highcharts JS API (formatter function) for this: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Here you can find an article explaining how you can do this in R:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR0fZ97iISS1_itErg69A6ncxI8R1JUuLVAzj4V_af7FE9oPkMBIPR3F9-I

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thought process. I've read the links you provided but it still makes no sense how I do what I want to do. I've never used JS before and have no CS background.  I get that I would use something like this: 
hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
                                return  value: {point.value:.3f}*100%<br>)
  }")

I don't understand what the syntax would be to multiply {point.value:.3f} by 100 or how to arrange it so that it works with the PointFormat= "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br> portion.   Any other suggestions on what I can read to understand this?

Comment: Here is an example of a working formatter: library('highcharter')
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "line",
    data = list(5, 4, 3, 5)
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
      var chart = this; 
      
      chart.update({
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
          }
        },
      });
    }
    ")
  ))

Comment: I understand what this code is doing and I can even manipulate it to multiply this.y by 100  but it still makes zero sense how I integrate this with my code. I can't get it to multiply the value in my treemap by 100.